# Who is node's father (Graph and tree data structure)?

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, c++14

I am working on some programing proble. You are given a graph(tree) with N nodes and N - 1 edges. To solve the problem, I need to know who is whos father here.

What is father of a node? Well, for example we have this tree: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aW9R.png). The father of node B is node F, the father of node E is node D, etc.. The only node that does not have father is F.

Since N <= 3 * 10^6, I need a O(N) solution for this. Any ideas how can I remember(in a vector for example) who is X's (X is a node) for every(1..N) node father?

Edit: I need to know father of every node in this tree, forgot to mention this relevant thing.

Comment: krrpffff...Node I am your father...krrpfff... (sorry couldnt resist)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't actually have a code. I am stuck at the very beggining. My first idea was dfs for every node, but that is too slow

Comment: Is it only for binary trees?

Comment: No, it's for every tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution. Just do a [Depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

If you remember where you are coming from you know the parent(father) of your current node.

Comment: Doesn't dfs goes always left? If so, I will not be able to know father of every node... Ooops I forgot that to mention, sorry

Comment: @Marko Milenkovic -You mean you want to know the root node?

Comment: I already know the root node. In my problem it is indexed with 1. And for all nodes that are connected with 1 we can say that their father is 1.

Comment: @Marko Milenkovic - A Breath first search wouldn't give you the parents fo each node but a Depth first search always goes from parent to child. If you remember where you come from you get the parent.

Comment: I get it, thanks! So, will this work (tatko[i] is the father of i):
void dfs(int x){

 for (auto& i : e[x]){
  if (i != tatko[x]){
   tatko[i] = x;
   dfs(i);
  }
 }

}